# Does lack of iterator invalidation imply anything about validity of advancing iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer

When the C++ standard says that an iterator is not "invalidated", is that merely referring to the ability to *dereference*, or does it imply something about the traversal capabilities as well?

For example, if the `swap`/`insert`/etc. of a container is guaranteed not to invalidate any iterators, does that fact *alone* imply it is also guaranteed that advancing an old iterator is also valid? And if so, is it guaranteed that it would traverse the elements in the same order as a fresh iterator would?

(I'm asking about traditional/"legacy" iterators here, though if there are any differences with the new style, it would be of course helpful to mention that as well.)

Comment: In what case would an insert not invalidate an iterator when the references to other objects aren't stored within the container?   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: If an iterator is not invalidated it remains valid (in every way). If it is invalidated it becomes invalid (for *all* purposes). What's not clear?

Comment: @Bryan Linked list?

Comment: Given part of the given use for iterators is it be able to *iterate* through data, I'd imagine it's baked into the iterator, and that any valid iterator should be able to advance, but I'll have to admit I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Bryan: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question. (Might be my lack of sleep today, but the double-negative and "other" objects are really confusing me for some reason.) If you still have the question could you please clarify what you're asking?

Comment: `And if so, is it guaranteed that it would traverse the elements in the same order as a fresh iterator would?` I am sure that depends on the guarantees provided by the container. For ordered containers `std::map std::set` then yes. For unordered containers `std::unordered_map or std::unordered_set` was there ever a guarantee about order?

Comment: @MartinYork: What about, say, `deque`?

Comment: "Does lack of iterator invalidation imply anything about validity of advancing iterator?" - Yes. Lack of *invalidation* implies it *stays valid*. If something is not invalidated, it is still valid.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: And the standard says "valid" means "nonsingular". That's all. And as I'm sure you know, an iterator that you can dereference but can't increment is still nonsingular. So as far as I can tell, validity says nothing about traversal.

Comment: @Mehrdad You've got me over the edge of my knowledge. I can't answer that authoritively with any relevant details - sorry. But it's an interesting question and I look forward to someone, more knowledgeable than me, providing an answer better than mine.

Comment: @Mehrdad For a case like `deque` rules are quite complex. However, `erase` does return an iterator to the next position after the erased item so using the return value, you would be able to advance in the container.

Comment: @Phil1970: See why it's not nearly as straightforward as you made it sound in your previous comment? :-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Welcome to the club! I've got myself over the edge of my knowledge too. ;) Now you see why I asked and why it's hardly obvious...

Comment: @Mehrdad Does an insertion into a Deque not invalidate all iterators?

Comment: @MartinYork: *Insertion* does, but `pop_back`/`swap`/etc. doesn't...

Comment: @Mehrdad Assuming deque guarantees ordered iterators (which I think it does but have not checked) then a valid iterator and new iterator would generate the same order of values (apart from the value you just swapped across the container). Nothing in the standard says that valid iterators will loose their ability to traverse a container (and you can't find a non statement).

Comment: @MartinYork: The thing is, to me it isn't as clear as "finding a non-statement". Iterator invalidation is something you can expect to happen on mutation of a container, especially if you don't know the implementation. The standard merely says "invalidates" or "does not invalidate" (or "has no effect on the validity of" , etc.). It also says an "invalid" iterator is one that *"may be singular"*. So by this logic, if I guarantee all iterators stay nonsingular, then I guarantee they all remain valid, and am complying with the standard. This says *nothing* about what happens if I traverse them.

Comment: The standard want to offer some minimal guarantee. For example, in the case of a `deque` if one only add or remove items at either end (and never in the middle), then it can keep pointers to those items permanently. Thus the rules are somewhat more complex to allows some specific patterns that might be useful in some applications where FIFO (first-in, first-out) is needed and you might need to keep some pointer to items in between during the processing.

Comment: @Mehrdad Say you have a vector of {a, b, c, d, e } and you erase item c. The standard say that iterator to a and b remain valid and those to d and e become invalide. In practice, iterator would probably point to d instead of c but as the standard say it is invalidated, then you should not use it anyway. If you want to continue iteration after erasing the item, then you should keep an iterator to b before erasing c and then advance b. In practice, in such case, it is usually best to use algorithm like `std::remove_if / std::erase` and not have to deal explicitly with invalidation rules.

Answer (score 5):

> "When the C++ standard says that an iterator is not "invalidated", is that merely referring to the ability to dereference, or does it imply something about the traversal capabilities as well?"

If an iterator is not invalidated it remains valid (in every way). If it is invalidated it becomes invalid (for all purposes (which my or may not include dereference, depending on the iterator)).
There's no distinction between "valid for dereference" and "valid for increment". It's either *valid* or *invalid*, for *any* purpose. Quite binary.

The only thing in the standard explicitly about invalid iterators:

> In: n4820
>
> #### 23.3.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]
>
> 15 An invalid iterator is an iterator that may be singular.<sup>233</sup>
>
> Note: 233) This definition applies to pointers, since pointers are iterators. The effect of dereferencing an iterator that has been invalidated is undefined.

### Singular Values:

> #### 23.3.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]
>
> 7 ... Results of most expressions are undefined for **singular** values; the only exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a **singular** value, the assignment of a non-singular value to an iterator that holds a **singular** value, and, for iterators that meet the Cpp17DefaultConstructible requirements, using a value-initialized iterator as the source of a copy or move operation. ...

Comment: Any chance you could point to where in the standard it says this? (The entire reason I asked was that I had the same hunch, but didn't find much support for it in the standard.)

Comment: @Mehrdad then maybe add [language-lawyer] tag?

Comment: @Mehrdad The best I could find in 30sec was http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#:unordered_associative_containers,iterator_invalidation But I'm quite sure there's something more specific in there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Yeah that doesn't seem specific enough to me. You can easily keep the order of elements in the container the same without making it possible for old iterators to be able to still traverse them (let alone in the same order). For what it's worth, I even see the language *"`i` is a valid dereferenceable iterator of `x`."* in the standard, which almost seems to suggest a valid iterator need not be dereferenceable (?!), let alone advanceable...

Comment: @Mehrdad **end** iterator is a typical case of a valid iterator that is not dereferenceable (for ex. in a `std::vector`)

Comment: @Phil1970: That seems... weird? It would imply an end iterator can't be singular, but why can't it? As long as it's unidirectional then it should be fine, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad Why is that weird? The end iterator is defined as pointing to "one past the end", so decrementing it is valid, testing against it is valid, but dereferencing it is not (since it doesn't refer to an element of the container).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: You can't decrement a *unidirectional* iterator though? I mean, just imagine a forward iterator that becomes singular (maybe it sets all its internal pointer(s) to `NULL`) as soon as it's incremented past the end of its sequence. It seems like a completely legit end iterator to me. But it would be singular. Why shouldn't that be allowed?

Comment: @Mehrdad That doesn't sound like a valid iterator to me. Even if I increment it one-past-the-end, I should still be able to decrement it and get at the last element. Just incrementing it past the end shouldn't (by itself) cause it to become invalid. For a unidirectional iterator - sure, that's a different matter. But still, either some operation invalidates the iterator or it stays valid.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: If the claim is that an end iterator *must* be valid, that implies it must be nonsingular so *even if it is unidirectional*. Which would imply it's *not* 'a different matter', but which I'm pointing out would be a bizarre restriction -- hence why I'm questioning whether an end iterator is necessarily valid.

Comment: @Mehrdad `std::vector::end()` is most certainly a *valid* iterator. If it was not, how would you be able to ever use it? Why would it exist?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: `std::vector::end` is not **unidirectional**. Nobody said `std::vector::end` can be invalid. But tell me why a **unidirectional** end iterator can't be invalid. It seems to me that it can, which would imply an end iterator need not always be valid.

Comment: @Mehrdad You have now officially exceed my knowledge of the details of the standard. I cannot answer that. 

Comment: @Mehrdad: Paragraph 7 of  [iterator.requirements.general] `Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called past-the-end value. Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable. Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence.`

Comment: @MartinYork: Not sure what you want me to take away from that. It's not hard to argue that a past-the-end unidirectional iterator isn't associated with any sequence.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are probably aware that on invalidation might affect **iterators at a specific position** or **all iterators** that point into a given container.

For example, if you **add an item** inside a `std::vector`, then a memory reallocation might occurs and any iterators for that containers would become invalide. In that case, the iterator would be clearly invalide both for advancing and dereferencing as a iterator inside a `std::vector` is essentially a pointer.

For other container like a `std::set`, if one **erase an item**, then only iterators pointing to the deleted item become invalide. You cannot move or dereference that iterator. However, because other iterators are not affected, you can easily make a copy of the iterator and advance it to next position (or anywhere else) before erasing an element and then use that iterator afterwards.

```
std::set<int> my_set;  // fill with some data…

auto it = my_set.find(42);
if (it != my_set.end())
{
    auto it2 = it;
    ++it2;
    my_set.erase(it);
    it = it2; // for example in a loop instead of ++it when a match is found.
}
```

At the end of the above code, `it` will be valid. It would be dereferencable only if not at the end (in that case, if there were number after 42 in the set).

As you can see from example, the fact that an iterator is dereferencable depends if there is data at that position or not.

**If the standard say that an iterator is invalidated**, then you should not use that iterator for sure (without setting it to another valid position first).